# Mixing Javascript inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

There isa  `D3.js` drawing function that is accepting `element` and `d` as data for its params and inside that function there are some HTML lines like this that draw some stuff:

```
'<p><strong>' + d.name_detail[0].detail_value + '</strong> ' + d.name_detail[1].detail_value +
'<strong class="pharmacy-icon">' + d.generic_tooltip.length +
'<img src="/assets/pill.png">' +
'</img></strong></p>' +
```

Notice the line  `'<img src="/assets/pill.png">' +`
I need to put some logic in there to say for example `if d.showpill === true` then show the pill icon otherwise don't show it.  But currently it is always showing.

Comment: @BentOnCoding : I didn't know what to try really. I am new to all this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if inline:

```
((d.showpill == true) ? '<img src="/assets/pill.png"> : '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'<p><strong>' + d.name_detail[0].detail_value + '</strong> ' + d.name_detail[1].detail_value +
'<strong class="pharmacy-icon">' + d.generic_tooltip.length +
(d.showpill === true ?'<img src="/assets/pill.png"></img></strong></p>' : '</strong></p>')
```

Comment: Is there some kind of syntax error in there? Now it draws nothing. :(